# Way to control location of Azure Vault used for backup?

Tags: azure

I'm backing up my VM using a Vault in the same Storage Group but noticed that is was sent to GRS instead of LRS. GRS is double the price and I don't need anything better than LRS. I've checked the vault and backup setting but don't see a way to change or even configure that from the start.

Is there an option that I'm missing or is this controlled by Microsoft. On-line documents seem to indicate that is can be controlled but don't show how/where.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, currently, we could not change the storage replication type if you have set up or have used this recovery service vault for backup. For the first time, you deploy this recovery service vault, you could change the storage replication type from GRS to LRS in the Azure portal.

[image]

[image]

In this case, you have to remove the old one and create a new vault. Refer to [changing Azure Recovery Services Vault to LRS Storage](https://thetechl33t.com/2017/05/06/changing-azure-recovery-services-vault-to-lrs-storage/). You also could vote this similar user voice [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/258995-azure-backup/suggestions/9273282-migrate-data-from-grs-to-lrs).